Adjetivos de color
¡Nos faltan palabras!
Suelen decir que el Inglés tiene más palabras que el Español. No lo he corroborado. Respecto a colores, en Inglés el adjetivo hacia un color se resuelve con el sufijo -ish. Así "rojizo" es "redish", de "red" + "-ish". Personalmente me gustan mucho más las palabras únicas como "grisáceo", "blancuzco" o "amarillento". El problema es que estas palabras no cubren todos los colores, mientras que el sufijo -ish se aplica a cualquiera. Por ejemplo para "ocre" o "beige", ejemplos que se me ocurren en primer instancia, no existen adjetivos equivalentes en español, mientras que en inglés si. Ni "ocreroso", ni "beigeoso".
Si no hay una palabra única, ¿cuál es el modo de denominar la tendencia de un color hacia otro?

Blanco tirando a beige?
Blanco casi beige?
¿?




Color
Adjetivo Inglés
Adjetivo Español




Azul
Bluish
Azulado


Amarillo
Yellowish
Amarillento


Blanco
Whitish
Blancuzco


Coral
Coralish
Coralino


Cyan
Cyanish
Cianoso


Gris
Grayish
Grisáceo


Marrón
Brownish
Amarronado, marronoso


Naranja
Orangish
Anaranjado


Negro
Blackish
Negruzco


Rojo
Redish
Rojizo


Rosa
Pinkish
Rosáceo, rosado


Verde
Greenish
Verdoso


Violeta
Purplish
Violáceo


Beige
Beigish
?


Ocre
Ocherish
?




The suffix -ish is much more widely used in English than just for colours of course. My cousin messaged me that they would arrive at 1130ish.

I didn't know that. Could be "casi" in Spanish.

I suspect there is some rule for when we can use -ish but I have no idea what it is. I can remember Spanish colleagues being quite amused by its many uses which vindicates your suggestion that Spanish lacks something quite so productive.

I've actually always found English very useful, I have a lot of words that sound very rounded to me in English without an immediate equivalent in Spanish.

I'd say "blanquecino" for "whitish"

Según el DRAE:

beis

adj. Dicho de un color: Castaño claro. U. t. c. s. m.

Sin.:  beige, ocre.

Es decir beige, beis y ocre son sinónimos según el DRAE. Aunque algunos estándares de impresión, como Pantone, consideran que ocre y beige son colores completamente distintos según apunta @user37164.
Si buscamos ocre


adj. De color ocre.

Sin.:
amarillento, tostado, terroso, pardo.

Con lo cual entiendo que la respuesta que ofrece el DRAE a los dos interrogantes en tu tabla es amarillento o cualquiera de los otros indicados en esa línea.
Wikipedia también nos ofrece varias alternativas, dependiendo del color que predomine en ese ocre

Ocre (del latín ochra, y este del griego ὤχρα, ojra, de ὠχρός, ojros,
‘amarillo’) es el nombre que se aplica típicamente a un mineral
terroso consistente en óxido de hierro hidratado, que frecuentemente
se presenta mezclado con arcilla, y que suele ser amarillento,
anaranjado o rojizo

Viendo el amplio espectro de colores que cubre la palabra "ocre" quizás no es la más adecuada para describir por si sola el color específico de una cosa y deba ir acompañada por otra a la cual aplicar ese equivalente del -ish: ocre amarillento, ocre anaranjado, ocre rojizo.

Por otro lado, y tal como muestras en la tabla, existen sufijos equivalentes en castellano al -ish del inglés. Otra cosa distinta es que aplicados a ocre o beige nos resulten extraños por el uso poco común de esos adjetivos derivados. Palabras como ocrino, ocruzco, ocroso, beisáceo, ... entiendo que serían válidas de acuerdo con la definición de los respectivos sufijos.

Si, los adjetivos se usan en general en colores puros. Igual el tema es que en Inglés no solo son para colores básicos sino que lo aplican a cualquiera, o casi. Ejemplos como magenta o fucsia no tienen equivalencias.

@Danielillo Quizás es que no entiendo del todo bien la pregunta. En español existen sufijos equivalentes al -ish en este contexto, como aquellos que has empleado en la tabla. He añadido un párrafo más

Los códigos RGB (pantallas), RAL (pintura), PMS (impresión), CYMK (tinta de impresora), etc... para componer el beige y el ocre son completamente diferentes entre sí: para todas las aplicaciones técnicas, desde luego no son sinónimos el uno del otro.

@user37164 No entiendo bien la puntualización. Cada standard o cada fabricante habrá decidido como haya querido cuales son las variables que generan lo que ellos consideran "beige" y "ocre", estupendo. En la foto está claro que usando una sola palabra, ocre, es dificil identificar un color concreto. Yo veo tres diferentes, no sé tú o el encargado de mezclas de HP o el de Pantone

@RubioRic: Dentro de cualquier paleta de colores, nunca encontrarás el mismo código para el beige y el ocre. Para ser verdaderos sinónimos, como establece la RAE, deberían tener el mismo código

@user37164 No funciona así el tema. Me refiero a ¿la RAE debe cambiar dependiendo de lo que diga Pantone? Rojo no tiene el mismo código en RGB y Pantone, ¿rojo no es sinónimo de rojo entonces? Sigo sin pillarlo

@RubioRic: Debería ser así: en la paleta de colores Pantone, el beige y el ocre nunca tienen el mismo código.

Quizás esta fuente lo diga de forma más sencilla: el beige es un color claro y neutro que suele describirse como una mezcla de marrón claro y gris. El ocre, en cambio, es un color cálido y terroso que va del marrón amarillento al naranja. Tienen matices diferentes y no se consideran sinónimos.

@user37164 Venga, he editado el texto de la respuesta para añadir eso que apuntas.

Emm, no. No falta ninguna palabra. Las palabras que estás buscando son ocráceo y beige. La primera es una combinación de ocre con el sufijo que le da el significado correspondiente. La segunda se deja sin modificar porque se trata de un préstamo crudo sin adaptar (aparece en cursiva).
De paso, que no exista un sufijo universal como en el inglés no es un impedimento de nada. La buena práctica es consultar bases de datos para ver cuál es el sufijo más común y seguir la tendencia general. Si así y todo llegado el caso no encontrás ninguna de tus tentativas al consultar, podrías proponer una nueva palabra, que dicho sea de paso así es como funciona el lenguaje. Si así y todo llegado el caso aún te queda la duda sobre si está bien formada, escribile un tuit a la RAE y pediles que te sugieran la mejor estrategia para resolver la situación.
EDIT
En vista de algunos comentarios, indaguemos un poco más. Al parecer, alegan por ahí que, por ejemplo, no hay palabras sufijadas claramente asentadas para magenta o fucsia. En realidad, eso es una cuestión de criterio. Según el mío, optaría directamente por dejarlo invariante sin sufijo: un objeto rojo magenta o rojo fucsia, yo creo que en ambos casos funciona bien.
Si de todas formas por el motivo que fuere vamos a ponernos creativos, podríamos comenzar por remitirnos a la etimología. La ciudad de Magenta es la que dio origen al color homónimo. En italiano, el gentilicio es magentini por lo que adaptarlo como magentino no lo veo mal. Otras opciones podrían ser magentoso o magéntico. En cuanto a fucsia, existe el compuesto químico llamado fucsina, formado por sufijación. Así que fucsino podría entrar en la lista de candidatos. Personalmente, me gusta mucho más fúcseo pero no encontré ningún ejemplo aunque creo que se puede entender perfecto.
Insisto en que por el momento no va a haber una respuesta unívoca para estos ejemplos, pero no veo ningún impedimento para hacer lenguaje. No faltan palabras. Sobran candidatos, esa es la cuestión.

Lo del color seguido de una palabra para adjetivizarlo lo he visto en el nombramiento de los colores que usa la autoridad de tránsito en mi país para el color de un vehículo; he visto "rojo punzo", "café champaña", "plata escuna", etc.
